# How fix "org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect]"?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, mysql-8.0

I received an exception when starting the application:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:126)
```

I am using MySQL 8.0.

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.15</version>
</dependency>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/botdb?serverTimezone=UTC</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.useSSL">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</property>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According pom.xml you are currently using Hibernate 5.2.12. From [5.2 Javadocs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/) one can see that it does not have `MySQL8Dialect`.

[MySQL8Dialect](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQL8Dialect.html) was introduced in Hibernate 5.3 (see [Javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQL8Dialect.html)). Problem can be solved by updating to Hibernate to [5.3](https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/5.3/) or to [5.4](https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/5.4/).

If updating Hibernate is not an option, then one must create custom dialect. That can be as easy as simply copying `MySQL8Dialect.java` from newer version to your code base and referencing it from persistence.xml. Potentially minor modifications are necessary.

Answer (score 2):

[image: S]

Basically  if you use spring boot, you don't need to define Dialect on the properties file because boot will automatically define itself

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> please provide the new mysql 8 dialect to resolve this
> issue.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```